# Building HTML cordova app and running directly on physical device

Tags: application-development, html5

I've just finished to create simple HTML/Cordova application on Ubuntu.
It works fine on the desktop.
I just want now to build it, copy to real UBUNTU device and run it (Not from SDK).
Which files should I copy after the build and how can I run the application on the device?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test the app in your device, just plug the device to your development pc using a USB cable.

Assuming that your device is recognized by the OS, from the terminal and in app's root directory type:

`cordova run --device`

Cordova should build the app for your device's platform (assuming you have added a platform during development), copy it to the device and run it automatically.

Tested with Cordova 3.5, Ubuntu 14.04 development machine and Nexus 4 (Android) as the target platform.

For more info about the steps see the documentation for [platform guides](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides) and the documentation for the [CLI](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) (look for the line mentioning how to run on device *Alternately, you can plug the handset into your computer and test the app directly:*).

Comment: Is it possible to build the app, copy it using say FLASH and run directly without plugging the device to development PC?

Comment: from the root directory of your app just type `cordova build` and then check for the build app into `app_root_directory/platforms/your_platform/ant-build/` there you'll see the packaged app. For Android for example, it could be `app_root_directory/platforms/android/your_app.apk`

Comment: Thanks, and what is packaged app for UBUNTU platform?

Comment: As per [Ubuntu Cordova Documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/):   _4. Build the HTML5 app to all added platforms, including Ubuntu: $ cordova build That creates a click package suitable for use in Ubuntu._ So you will look for that inside the ubuntu platform directory.